# PHP to Google WebApp returns "<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>The document has moved"

Tags: php, html, authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know how to call a web app written in Google AppScript from PHP?

I've published my app to run as me and made it available to "everyone". The test url looks like this:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/xXxXxX/dev?Jobno=11&Pickupfrom=Aa&Deliverto=bb&Readyby=22&Deliverby=33
```

This link appends a new record into a google spreadsheet. The link only works if I submit it manually in a browser that is logged in to Google. If I log out of google it forwards me to a login page. This makes no sense to me. I don't understand why it's forcing authentication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The described behaviour is a feature:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects

> ## Redirects
>
> For security reasons, content returned by the Content service isn't served from script.google.com, but instead redirected to
>   a one-time URL at script.googleusercontent.com. This means that if you
>   use the Content service to return data to another application, you
>   must ensure that the HTTP client is configured to follow redirects.
>   For example, in the cURL command line utility, add the flag -L. Check
>   the documentation for your HTTP client for more information on how to
>   enable this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

**You just need to send a header to follow the url**

```
 curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

where $url is your url initialised with curl_init('apps script url') something like this:

`$url = curl_init('https://script.google.com/YOUR_APPS_SCRIPT_URL');`

add the line:

```
curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

only after you send the other important headers

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it has something to do with how it's published. Republish and change "Who has access to the app" to "Anyone, even anonymous" and you should resolve the problem.

Edit: also remember to save a new version before publishing

Comment: I did publish it so that anyone has access to it. I said "everyone" but that's what I meant.

Comment: I get the impression there is more to versioning than is obvious to me. I've made a lot of changes to the code since I saved the first version, however, since I haven't got it to work yet I just keep saving without updating the version. It doesn't make sense to me that I should update the version for every experimental tweak that hasn't even been tested yet. Since I keep reading such warnings about updating the version I'm starting to wonder if I should. Is that possibly what's preventing this from working?

Comment: Your comment here proves that I'm right ;-) the .dev url is actually there to test your code manually, only the script editor can run it, not an external PHP script. So save a new version when your manual tests are ok (which is the case apparently) and try again, it will work !

Comment: please read [this doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions#createVersion) carefully, it explains the versioning concept quite clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "exec" version of your app, not the "dev" one.

And, as mentioned in the other answer, don't forget to save a version and update your deployment with this latest version.

The "dev" version is only used for test and is only accessible by the script editors when they are logged in.

Your url should look like this :

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/xXxXxX/exec?Jobno=11&Pickupfrom=Aa&Deliverto=bb&Readyby=22&Deliverby=33
```

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing. It didn't work but clearly there is more to be learned about this. I have spent hours trying to figure this out and I've never seen that anywhere. Where do I learn more about this exec vs. dev stuff?

Comment: the documentation explains the [3 necessary steps you must follow to deploy a webApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#deploying)   If my solution didn't work it is most probably because you didn't save a new version with your latest code and didn't choose this version from the deplyment menu.

Comment: I saved another version. I saved several new versions. I changed it from dev to exec. It still takes me to a login page when I try it in a browser that is not logged in to a google account.

Comment: "Saved a new version", that's fine but did you choose the latest one in the deployment window?

Comment: Yes, I did. I always select the latest version. Is there something I am supposed to do when I save or select the version that identifies this as the version that is supposed to work? :) I wish it were that easy.